# Magento 2 admin auto complete search

Tags: magento2

How can we integrate an auto complete search in admin custom form? I am not using the default form of Magento2. Instead I am using my custom form.

Comment: Like Admin Products Select Categories?

Comment: @AnkitShah, No like http://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-search-atocomplete-free.html this module

Comment: @VarunJyothi are you able to find this ?